# Null values parsing with GSON on Android/Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am trying to parse to/from JSON in an Android/Kotlin app using GSON. When I run this code both *foobar* and *jsonString* are null. What am I missing?

```
    var gson = Gson()

    data class Foobar( val foo: String )

    val foobar = gson.fromJson("""{"foo":"bar"}""",Foobar::class.java)
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(Foobar("bar"))
```

Comment: please could you include more code in your post, how/where are you calling this ? it seems to work for me

Comment: It's pretty much the only code running in the onCreate() of a trivial Android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making use of a basic unit test:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun fooTest() {

        var gson = Gson()

        data class Foobar( val foo: String )

        val foobar = gson.fromJson("""{"foo":"bar"}""",Foobar::class.java)
        val jsonString = gson.toJson(Foobar("bar"))

        assertEquals(null, foobar)
        assertEquals(null, jsonString)
    }
}
```

this test fails:

```
Expected :null<null> 
Actual   :java.lang.String<null>
```

moving the class outside of the method :

```
data class Foobar( val foo: String )

@Test
fun fooTest() {

    var gson = Gson()


    val foobar = gson.fromJson("""{"foo":"bar"}""",Foobar::class.java)
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(Foobar("bar"))

    assertEquals(null, foobar)
    assertEquals(null, jsonString)
}

Expected :null
Actual   :Foobar(foo=bar)
```

as well as

```
Expected :null
Actual   :{"foo":"bar"}
```

this is a good thing, this means that we were expecting it to be null, but instead the test failed because our variables actually had values. Your issue is caused by having the data class inside the method, in your case this method is onCreate, moving it out resolves the issue

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This worked.  I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure out what was wrong here!

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to mark the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Since this code is all in the *onCreate()* method of an Android class (*Main Activity*), *Foobar::class.java* didn't take into account the fact that the *Foobar* class is nested in the *MainActivity* class. So, this is also a fix:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        ...
        
        var gson = Gson()

        data class Foobar( val foo: String )

        val foobar = gson.fromJson(
                     """{"foo":"bar"}""",
                     MainActivity.Foobar::class.java)

        val jsonString = gson.toJson(Foobar("bar"))

        ...
    }
}
```